# Extracting and updating a dictionary from array of dictinaries in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a structure like this:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "user" : "somebody",
    "players" : [
        {
            "name" : "lala",
            "surname" : "baba",
            "player_place" : "1",
            "start_num" : "123",
            "results" : {
                "1" : { ... }
                "2" : { ... },
                ...
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I am pretty new to MongoDB and I just cannot figure out how to extract `results` for a specific `user` (in this case "somebody", but there are many other users and each has an array of players and each player has many results) for a specific `player` with `start_num`.

I am using pymongo and this is the code I came up with:

```
record = collection.find(
    {'user' : name}, {'players' : {'$elemMatch' : {'start_num' : start_num}}, '_id' : False}
)
```

This extracts `players` with specific player for a given user. That is good, but now I need to get specific result from `results`, something like this:
`{ 'results' : { '2' : { ... } } }`.

I tried:

```
record = collection.find(
    {'user' : name}, {'players' : {'$elemMatch' : {'start_num' : start_num}}, 'results' : result_num, '_id' : False}
)
```

but that, of course, doesn't work. I could just turn that to list in Python and extract what I need, but I would like to do that with query in Mongo.

Also, what would I need to do to replace specific result in `results` for specific player for specific user? Let's say I have a new result with key `2` and I want to replace existing result that has key `2`. Can I do it with same query as for `find()` (just replacing method `find` with method `replace` or `find_and_replace`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace a specific result and the syntax for that should be something like this,

assuming you want to replace the result with key 1,

```
collection.updateOne({
  "user": name,
  "players.start_num": start_num
},
{ $set: { "players.$.results.1" : new_result }})
```